# Unable to get element inside ifame in selenium

Tags: selenium, iframe

I am able to get 2nd frame but unable to get that `<p>` tag inside that frame tries with xpath throwing **unable to find element**

My code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("firstframe");
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElelemt(By.cssSelector());
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/p")).sendKey("test");
```

HTML:

```
<iframe id="firstframe">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="frdive">
          <div id="sndiv">
            <iframe class="test" title="test">
              <html style="overflow-y: hidden;">
                <head></head>
                <body>
                  <p></p>
                </body>
              </html >
            </iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</iframe>
```

Comment: may be the element is hidden. are you able to do it manually?

Comment: yes able to add value to it manually.

Answer (score 0):

After getting into the first frame, try switching with the below xpath.

```
"//iframe[@title='test']"
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: thanks Santhosh!! I am able to switch second frame with my code but not able to get  element in that frame.ie.<p> tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("firstframe");
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//iframe[@title='test']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/p"));
```

You can change to frame by Id, by Name or by WebElement.

Comment: Thats returns you a WebElement?

    `driver.switchTo().frame("firstframe");
    WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//iframe[@title='test']");
System.out.println(elem);`

An other debug, save the `driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/p"));` on a WebElement variable and print the isDisplayed and isEnabled properties. Maybe you have the element but no the options to interact with it.

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame("firstframe");
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElelemt(By.cssSelector()); is working but after that when I try to display driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElelemt(By.cssSelector()).getTitle();  it is throwing error unable to find element with Xpath

Comment: When you are on the correct iframe use directly driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//html/.//p")). You don't need use again driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElelemt(By.cssSelector())‌​

Comment: It is still throwing error unable to find element with xpath  .//html/.//p. When I checked in chrome with this path I am able to find element in html code, but when I tried in my code it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try with webdriver wait as given below. It may works for you.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("firstframe");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath(".//iframe[@title='test']"));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/p")).sendKey("test");
```